# how to combine multiple excel sheets data with distinct columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have thousands of excel files.Each excel file has different column names and sometimes there is no column name. I want to merge all this data into one dataframe. I want to create distinct columns in dataframe and get the data of all columns from all excel sheets.If column already present in dataframe , then only rows should merge into already presented column.In case there is no column with that name , it should create new column and merge data into that.

Any way possible ? would be glad if someone helps.thanks in advance.

Comment: two questions, are all the sheets you need to merge on the same sheet (for example do all n number of excel files all have the data you need one sheet_1)? second question, are all the excel files the same size (meaning do they have the same number of columns, in the same order)?

Comment: Answer for both questions is NO. There are multiple excel files and each has multiple worksheets. Different excel files has different size.

Comment: well, this would be very difficult, and I don't think anyone here could provide you with a piece of code that would fit your use case. I've had a similair issue with about 100 excel files where the data was on either sheet 1, sheet 2 or sheet 3. bugged the hell out of me. if the excel files are of different sizes then why do you want to merge them?

Comment: I understand. It is difficult indeed. But is there any way to store all the data into one df object with distinct columns ? forget about the database storing thing. I just want to store all the data into data frame.

Comment: You could but you'd get a mismatched df